# Como eliminar un evento especifico con Jquery

Tags: jquery, eventos, keypressevent

si por ejemplo en un objeto definimos 2 o mas eventos para un mismo objeto, todos los eventos con la misma funcion, ejemplo:

$('#elemento').on('keydown',function(){alert('Evento de prueba')});

Y la pagina que renderiza se recarga varias veces, no importa si esta mal o no, lo que importa es que el evento se va agregando, es decir por cada recarga se anida un evento, y al presionar la tecla va mostrando tantos alerts como veces se haya recargado la pagina (por ajax claro, sino se limpian los eventos).

mi consulta es: como puedo eliminar un evento especifico, es decir si tiene 3 eliminar solo el 2do evento y que quede el 1ro y el 3ro.

se puede hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas hacer uso de la función `off()` de JQuery, [en este enlace la explicación](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_off.asp), básicamente funciona así:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("p").off("click");
});
```

Este código eliminaría todos los eventos click del párrafo, al presiona un botón.

Por otro lado, si lo que quieres es eliminar solo un elemento específico, es necesario que este haya sido creado dentro de una función:

```
var foo = function() {
    alert($(this).val());
};

// foo será llamado cuando se de clic en los párrafos
$( "body" ).on( "click", "p", foo );

// ... Foo no volverá a ser llamado.
$( "body" ).off( "click", "p", foo );
```

Comment: si eso esta claro, el problema es que si asigno varias veces el evento click con diferentes funciones, como hago para selecciona el segundo por ejemplo, o el primero y que queden los otros activos, se entiende?

Comment: En el enlace que compartí se muestra como remover un evento pasando como parámetro la función inicial  con la que creaste el mismo. He editado la respuesta.